# java network launch protocol error

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, filenotfoundexception

I'm new in JNLP , when I run .jnlp it's run correctly , but when run it as embedded in html file the follow error is appeared  .

Please note that every thing is correctly , and run .

> file not found exception
>
> Java Plug-in 10.17.2.02 Using JRE version 1.7.0_17-b02 Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM User home directory = C:\Users\aladdin
>   ---------------------------------------------------- c:   clear console window f:   finalize objects on finalization queue g:
>   garbage collect h:   display this help message l:   dump classloader
>   list m:   print memory usage o:   trigger logging q:   hide console r:
>   reload policy configuration s:   dump system and deployment properties
>   t:   dump thread list v:   dump thread stack x:   clear classloader
>   cache 0-5: set trace level to 
>   ---------------------------------------------------- CacheEntry[file:DrawTest.jnlp]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Mon
>   Jun 10 16:42:04 AST 2013,length=555   Match: beginTraversal Match:
>   digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.6+, heap=-1--1, args=null,
>   href=null, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
>       platform is: 1.7
>       product is: 1.7.0_17
>       location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
>       path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
>       args is: 
>       native platform is: Windows, amd64 [ x86_64, 64bit ]
>       JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.7 found at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
>       enabled is: true
>       registered is: true
>       system is: true
>
> Match: ignoring maxHeap: -1     Match: ignoring InitHeap: -1    Match:
>   digesting vmargs: null    Match: digested vmargs: [JVMParameters:
>   isSecure: true, args: ]   Match: JVM args after accumulation:
>   [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]   Match: digest LaunchDesc:
>   file:DrawTest.jnlp    Match: digest properties: []    Match: JVM args:
>   [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]   Match: endTraversal ..
>     Match: JVM args final:      Match: Running JREInfo Version    match:
>   1.7.0.17 == 1.7.0.17   Match: Running JVM args match: have:<>  satisfy want:<>

Comment: This doesn't look like an error.  Looks like the normal output of the java console when running a webstart app.

Comment: the frame is empty and have in the left upper corner "error , click for details " and when i click , the above is shown

Comment: I see now the "file not found exception".  Do you get the same if you intentionally name your jars wrong, in the html/applet/object tag?  If so your reference/path to those jars is probably just wrong.

Comment: no it does not same  , "the system cannot find the file specific" .
hence , I'm sure all correctly i wrote .

Comment: Could "file not found exception" be coming from your application?  Does it attempt to open files.  Applets have fewer privileges on the files system than normal apps.  Also, running from within the browser any relative file paths will be interpreted differently.

Comment: it's from my application , but not attempt to use any recourse outside the code itself

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/). 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.